# Text File as Matrix

Tags: python-2.7

How do I read a text file as if it were a matrix without using numphy or any additional programs. For example:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, 8
9, 10, 11, 12
```

I want to read the list as if it were a matrix -- reading each column as if it were one category L[0], L[1], L[2], and L[3]. I want to take the mean of each column, but I need to know how to read the text file accordingly.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
matrix = []  # create an empty matrix. We'll add entries to it from the file soon
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for line in infile:  # for each line in the file
        row = [float(i) for i in line.strip().split(',')]  # turn each element in the line into a floating point number
        matrix.append(row)  # treat that line of floating point numbers as a list, and add it as a row of the matrix

cols = zip(*matrix)  # transpose the matrix to get the columns
means = [sum(col)/len(col) for col in cols]  # compute the mean of each column
```